# How can I get the left "Tableview" in iTunes? 

Tags: cocoa, macos, itunes

How can I make the left side use a tableview? It has the music, films, etc. How can I use it in my cocoa app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `NSOutlineView` with a source list highlight. `NSOutlineView` is a Cocoa class and available in Interface Builder.

Alternatively, you can use [Perspx’ PXSourceList](http://perspx.com/work/).

Comment: i think i will take the pxsource list because it looks better :D